# Jordan decomposition of an endomorphism with minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ of characteristic zero. Below is a proof of the fact that if $T\in\text{End}(V)$ and $T$ admits a minimal polynomial with distinct roots $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, then
$$
V=N_1\oplus\cdots\oplus N_n,
$$
where $N_k=\ker (T-\lambda_k\,I)$.

> **Question:** does the result still hold if we relax the condition on the characteristic? On the simplicity of the roots?

Here is the proof. Consider the polynomial
$$
q(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{j\ne k}\frac{(t-\lambda_j)}{(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)}
$$
This is well-defined because $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are distinct. We have $q(\lambda_k)=1$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$. As the degree of $q$ is $n-1$, we deduce that $q(t)=1$ for all $t$. Then $q(T)=I$. For any $x\in V$, we can write $x=q(T)x$, i.e.
$$\tag{1}
x=\sum_{k=1}^n\,\prod_{j\ne k}\frac{(T-\lambda_j\,I)\,x}{(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)} .
$$
It is clear that $\prod_{j\ne k}\frac{(T-\lambda_j\,I)\,x}{(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)}\in N_k$, since 
$$
(T-\lambda_k\,I)\,\prod_{j\ne k}\frac{(T-\lambda_j\,I)\,x}{(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)}=p(T)x=0.
$$
Finally, if $y\in N_k\cap N_j$ for $k\ne j$, then $$0=Ty-\lambda_ky=Ty-\lambda_jy,$$
so $(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)y=0$. As $\lambda_k-\lambda_j\ne0$, we have $y=0$. So the decomposition $(1)$ is indeed a direct sum.

The fact that $p$ is the minimal polynomial guarantees that $N_k\ne\{0\}$ for all $k$: if, for example, $N_1=\{0\}$, then $(T-\lambda_2\,I)\cdots(T-\lambda_n\,I)x=0$ for all $x\in V$, and then $p$ would not be minimal.

Comment: This proof works in any characteristic. Now, if $T\neq 0$, but $T^2=0$, then $ker(T)\neq V$. So we can not drop the simplicity.

Comment: Should that $\prod_{j \neq k}$ be there?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: good point, edited. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof works over any characteristic.  In particular, you are only every dividing by $\lambda_j - \lambda_k$, and this is fine as long as $\lambda_j \neq \lambda_k$.

The simplicity assumption cannot be dropped.  The matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
is a consistent counterexample.